# Negative Kinetic energy of normal modes in an elastic solid?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, elasticity, normal-modes

So I'm pretty stupid, admittedly, but I'm also pretty confused. I also fully realize this question is probably completely idiotic.

The background is normal modes in linear elastic solids.

Let the displacement of a particle from some eq. position within a solid be (a normal mode)

$$u_i(\mathbf{x},t) = u_0^{(i)}e^{i(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x} - \omega t)}$$

Where $i = 1...3$ corresponds to the $x,y,z$ directions.

I'm trying to find the kinetic energy (density) within the elastic solid. Provided the mass density is $\rho$, then the kinetic energy should be

$$ K_E = \frac{1}{2} \rho \sum_{i = 1}^{3} \left(\frac{\partial{u_i}}{\partial t}\right)^2 $$

So, it's pretty easy to show that

$$
\frac{\partial{u_i}}{\partial t} = -i\omega u_i(\mathbf{x},t) 
$$

Which implies, of course,

$$
\left(\frac{\partial{u_i}}{\partial t} \right)^2= (-1)^2i^2\omega^2 u_i^2(\mathbf{x},t)  = -\omega^2u_i^2$$

Which gives, for the kinetic energy then

$$
K_E = -\frac{1}{2} \rho \omega^2 \sum_{i = 1}^{3} u_i^2 
$$

But this is pretty obviously wrong. It should be

$$
\boxed{K_E = \frac{1}{2} \rho \omega^2 \sum_{i = 1}^{3} u_i^2 }
$$

Buuuut....it's not. So what the hell is going on? Can someone explain what I'm not seeing? Can someone at least point to some possible failures in my logic? I'm perplexed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The displacement obviously can't be a complex number, so your first equation is wrong. You probably meant to take the real part of the right hand side.

Comment: If you wrote cosine(kx-wt) instead of exp(kx-wt) would you still have trouble?

Comment: Yeah, supposing $Re[u_i] = u_i^{(0)}\cos(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x} - \omega t) \equiv u_{i,R}$,
Then $u_{i,R;t} = \omega u_i^{(0)}\sin(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x} - \omega t)$, and 

$$ K_E = \frac{1}{2}\rho\omega^2 \sum_{i}(u_i^{(0)})^2\sin^2(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x} - \omega t) \neq\frac{1}{2}\rho\omega^2 \sum_{i} u_i^2 $$

Comment: @GeneralPancake So now the only difference is a cosine versus a sine. But this is correct. The regions where it displaced farther from equilibrium really do have less kinetic energy and where it has the most kinetic energy it has the least displacement away from equilibrium. But now if you average over a wavelength or over a period then everything is fine.

Comment: Right, I can see that, but it's still really important we be able to write $$
\boxed{K_E = \frac{1}{2} \rho \omega^2 \sum_{i = 1}^{3} u_i^2 }
$$

It's kinda integral to the whole discussion. You have to be able to write the kinetic energy that way because it goes into a Lagrangian, and if it's not written that way the whole thing kinda falls apart. 

At least as far as I know. I'm not smart enough to do anything other than exactly what the book I'm reading says. The best I can do is justify each individual part as best as possible.

Comment: ----------
Okay, like even look at [This paper](http://scholarworks.montana.edu/xmlui/bitstream/handle/1/1253/FigM1205.pdf?sequence=1). (Also note, Einstein notation)

He writes 

$$K_E = \frac{1}{2}\rho\frac{\partial{\hat{u}_i}}{\partial t}\frac{\partial{\hat{u}_i}}{\partial t}$$

Then, provided 
$$\hat{u}_i(\mathbf{x},t) = u_i(\mathbf{x})e^{i\omega t} $$

Then 

$$K_E = \frac{1}{2} \rho \omega^2 u_i u_i e^{2i\omega t}$$

Where, of course, I get 

$$K_E = - \frac{1}{2} \rho \omega^2 u_i u_i e^{2i\omega t}$$

So obviously it's *not* just about taking the real part.